# Windows computer account appears to reset its own password, why?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, password-reset

Has anyone seen this where a computer account appears to reset its password?

The password for user 'WEST\SQLCLUSTER$' was reset by 'WEST\SQLCLUSTER$' on 'DOMAINCONTROLLER.WEST.company.corp' at '04/23/10 20:47:41'
Event Type:     Success Audit

Event Source:   Security

Event Category: Account Management

Event ID:       628

Date:           Friday, April 23, 2010

Time:           8:47 PM

User:           WEST\SQLCLUSTER$

Computer:       DOMAINCONTROLLER.WEST.company.corp

Description:
User Account password set:

```
     Target Account Name:        SQLCLUSTER$

     Target Domain:      WEST

     Target Account ID:      WEST\SQLCLUSTER$

     Caller User Name:       SQLCLUSTER$

     Caller Domain:      WEST

     Caller Logon ID:        (0x0,0x7A518945)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is expected, normal, and good. Any computer running Windows 2000 or later will automatically change its computer account password every 30 days. This is a security mechanism. See [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/askds/archive/2009/02/15/test2.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the case, I generated a report of event ID 628's over the past 2 months and I don't see any other computer accounts changing passwords.  Only the computer listed in the example has done so and it's changed the password 3 or 4 times since the beginning of March.